# Add a button at the last cell of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have 2 `UITableView` to filter out 2 category,

my category is cat and dog, 1st `UITableView` that handles cat and 2nd `UITableView` that handles dog.

What i want is to have cat and dog into one UITableview,
so the in the `UITableView`, the first part will be the cats, and the second part is the dog. what i want to do is to put a button above the dog part where it will be used as a separator for two category.

this is the illustration:
[image]

the 2 cells in the top is the cat 
and the one cell in the bottom is a dog there should be a button in the middle of the two category as a seperator.

Comment: you can create 2 section, 1 is for cat and 2nd is for dog, you can add button in `viewForHeader` method.

Comment: @Kuldeep i would appreciate if you can clarify more, i kinda new to ios development.

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou please refer this link  https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-enums-and-uitableview-sections-1806b74b8138

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou, review my answer.

Comment: @JigarDarji this is helpful when it comes in constructing the logic, but i'm using objective - c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *arrCat;
    NSArray *arrDog;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    arrCat = @[@"Cat 1", @"Cat 2", @"Cat 3", @"Cat 4", @"Cat 5"];
    arrDog = @[@"Dog 1", @"Dog 2", @"Dog3 ", @"Dog4 ", @"Dog 5"];
}
```

I have Programatically create Header, You can also create it by creating xib.
Add `UITableView` delegate and DataSource like this.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return arrCat.count;
    }
    return arrDog.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.lblCategory.text = arrCat[indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        cell.lblCategory.text = arrDog[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 60)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = view.frame;
    button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    button.titleLabel.textColor     = [UIColor blackColor];
    [view addSubview:button];

    if (section == 0) {
        [button setTitle:@"CAT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [button setTitle:@"DOG" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return view;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 60.0;
}
```

Comment: give me time to translate this to objective - c.

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou, wait I am updating my answer with objective C.

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou, Review my updated answer.

Comment: Would it be possible to collapse and expand the category using the buttons? like if i want to hide the cat's list category by clicking to the button.

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou, for expand collapse, need to change logic.